# Scala: Splitting a string into two integers

Tags: scala, split

This is my current code. I want to split a string into two integers and stock them into variables.

```
val line = "1 2"
var a = 0
var b = 0
val c = line.split(" ") match { case Array(x,y) => (x.toInt, y.toInt) }
a = c._1
b = c._2
```

Is there any way to do something like this in Scala ? This is much more compact.

```
(a,b) = line.split(" ") match { case Array(x,y) => (x.toInt, y.toInt) }
```

The expression line.split(" ") match { case Array(x,y) => (x.toInt, y.toInt) } returns a tupple of integers so I thought directly linked the two integers with the variables a and b would work.

Comment: `val List(a, b) = line.split(" ").toList`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This is much more compact and clean**

```
val Array(a,b) = line.split("\\s+").map(_.toInt)
```

*Following code works even if there are more numbers in the string*

```
val Array(a, b, _*) = line split "\\s+" map(_ toInt)
```

*dot optional*

```
val Array(a,b) = line split("\\s+") map(_.toInt)
```

*what about this ?*

```
val Array(a,b) = line split "\\s+" map(_ toInt)
```

**For more specific case do this**

```
val Array(a, ' ', b) = "1 2".toCharArray
```

*Scala REPL*

```
scala> val line = "1 2"
line: String = "1 2"
scala> val Array(a,b) = line.split("\\s+").map(_.toInt)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2

scala> val line = "1 2 3  4"
line: String = "1 2 3  4"
scala> val Array(a, b, _*) = line split "\\s+" map(_ toInt)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2

scala> val Array(a, ' ', b) = "1 2".toCharArray
a: Char = '1'
b: Char = '2'
```

Comment: just a quick comment, correct me if i'm wrong. Pattern match works with Array because `split` is a method from Java String and returns `String[]` - so array of strings. Conceptually it will return `List[String]` or even `Iterable[String]`

Comment: @ysusuk you need unapply method for pattern matching to work

Comment: this is clear. i was just theorising that if i would implement Scala `String` i would return a `List[String]` or `Iterable[String]` on `split` . `List` has `unapply` and `Iterable` will fallback to `List` as it's `default` implementation.

Comment: val Array(a, ' ', b) = "1 2".toCharArray this is even more clean

Comment: val Array(a, _, b) = "1 2".toCharArray

Answer (score 1):

`val List(a, b) = line.split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList`

Comment: why using a List ?

Comment: it works very well with Array as in @pamu example. It is conceptual way to unpack elements from list if it is the list of params or config list, so when elements have identity (meaning). Not just a list of ints or strings but in our case 1 can be the number of test casses, 2 - can be the number of elements in each test case or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a `case` class to encapsulate your data point:

```
  case class Datom(x: Int, y: Int)

  val datom = "1 2".split(" ") match { case Array(x, y) => Datom(x.toInt, y.toInt) }
  println(s"x = ${datom.x}, y = ${datom.y}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
val (d, e) = line.split(" ") match { case Array(x,y) => (x.toInt, y.toInt) }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val str = "1 2"

val res = str.split(" ") 
val a = res.head.toInt 
val b = res.last.toInt
```

`a` and `b` are your required vaiables.

Comment: `val res = str.split(" ").map(_.toInt) `   and then res(0) res(1)